# Error handling when getElementByClass fails to return data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know how error handeling works in these kinds of situations. I'm scraping prices of a page, 10 items. If 1 item is sold out, the price disappears. The scraper breaks because it's looking for a class that's not here, so it needs an error handler that prints something like "Error, sold out". I haven't got a clue how to do this. Could someone point me to a good read so I can learn how error handlers work?

```
const prijs = await page.evaluate(
    () => document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText;// Error handling needed here
);
```

Comment: The documentation on [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) would have told you that it returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (an array-like structure, hence the `[0]`) which also has a _length_.

Comment: so called attributes seem to be tricky thing ;)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right way, that helped me alot and it was a good read.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const prijs = await page.evaluate(
  () => {
        var results = document.getElementsByClassName("price")
        return results.length ? results[0].innerText : "Error, sold out"
    }
);
```

Where you would check if the actual array has elements and if not return the error string.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me in my project. I shall use this method in the future.